# javascript removeAttribute and setAttribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want change `id` secend `input:file`, i try as following javascript code, but dont work for me. what do i do?

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KZ57Z/**

Html:

```
<div id="UpUp">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="fileElem" multiple>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="fileElem" multiple> // this must change
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="fileElem" multiple>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var getThis = $('#UpUp > input:nth-child(2)');
getThis.removeAttribute("id");
getThis.setAttribute("id", 'unique')
```

Comment: close ur <p> tags ..else 2nd and 3rd input file elements not get loaded.

Comment: Why is the HTML in your question different from that in your demo? Why are you (apparently) using jQuery, but not including the library in your demo? Why are you fetching a jQuery object but then using native DOM methods on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`removeAttribute` and `setAttribute` are not part of the [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/). If you want to modify an attribute with jQuery, you'd use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) (there's no need to remove the existing attribute first):

```
$('#UpUp > input:nth-child(2)').attr('id', 'unique');
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KZ57Z/8/)

Comment: @TaylorGomez, you're missing the attribute name of `'id'` (you probably copied it off of an earlier version of my answer which had a typo)

Comment: @TaylorGomez, more importantly, your HTML doesn't match what you posed in your question. You've got some additional `p` elements getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

The exact syntaxes are [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [.removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/). And you can use them to manipulate the attributes. And by the way you are having some `invalid markups` in your fiddle. I Just corrected it and made a demo for you. But keep in mind that here after, don't forget to add the jquery library to your html file before using it.

```
var getThis = $('#UpUp > input:nth-child(2)');
getThis.removeAttr("id");
getThis.attr("id", 'unique');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KZ57Z/9/)

Comment: @Raj: You don't need the `.removeAttr()` part. And the HTML markup in OP's demo isn't invalid.

Comment: @BlueSkies I just answered him in the way he asked the question. See the 2nd child in his fiddle is a <p> tag. So I meant invalid markup in the perspective of the jquery he had written. :)

Comment: Yes, the markup (or the selector) was certainly problematic if he was trying to target the second input. OP should still drop the `.removeAttr()` since there's no real point to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#UpUp > input:eq(1)').attr('id', 'unique');
```

Comment: Are you sure you're including jquery correctly? Works here http://jsfiddle.net/zRTRU/